# Getting mbid of a track from lastfm: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python

I have the tracks{} that stores some information about tracks using the last fm api. Now I want to store the mbid of each track in tracks{} the  but it is appearing the error:

```
  mbid = track['mbid']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

`print(track)` returns:

```
name
mbid
url
duration
....
```

`print(track_mbid_response)` have this format:

```
{'track': {'name': 'Achtung Baby', 'mbid'.....:
```

Do you know where is the issue?

```
for i, v in tracks.items():
    artist = tracks[i]['artist'].replace(" ", "+")
    title = tracks[i]['title'].replace(" ", "+")


    track_mbid =  requests.get('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.getInfo&format=json&api_key=' + api_key + '&artist=' + artist + '&track=' + title)
    track_mbid_response = track_mbid.json()

    #print(track_mbid_response)

    for track in track_mbid_response['track']:
        #print(track)

        mbid = track['mbid']
        print(mbid)

        tracks[ID]['mbid'] = tracks[i]['mbid']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating over the *keys* in track. just do `track = track_mbid_response["track"]` and then you can add to that dict.